# How to make select multiple and single on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a javascript that controls the display of a DIV base on the dropdown select of another DIV. The first dropdown has a list of one, multiple, and none. When single is selected I want it to change the second DIV dropdown select to single, when multiple selected should make it multiple and when the none is selected it should change it to single select. Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSecondDropdown(){
let firstDrop = document.getElementById("blocation");
let text = firstDrop.options[firstDrop.selectedIndex].text;
let secondDrop = document.getElementById("subtype");
document.getElementById("subtypeDiv").style.display = "block";}
</script>

<!--- First DIV ------->
                  <div>
                        <label for="sampleRecipientInput">How many physical locations you have *</label>
                        <div class="ss-custom-select">
                            <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation" onchange="setSecondDropdown()">
                                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>
                                
                                <option value="One">One</option>
                                <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
                                <option value="Online">None (ex. online only)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                            <p id = "displayLocationError" style="color: red"></p>                              
                  </div>

<!----- Second DIV ------->
                  <div>
                        <label for="sampleRecipientInput">Subtype of business?</label>
                        <div class="ss-custom-select" id="subtypeDiv" style="display: none;">
                            <select class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="false">
                                
                                <option value=""  disabled selected hidden>Select the subtype of business</option>
                                    </select>
                        </div>      
                            <p id = "displaySubTypeError" style="color: red"></p>                   
                                
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have not understood your problem properly. Here is my suggestion, correct me something else was desired.

Remove onchange="setSecondDropdown()" and use below code

```
const firstD=document.getElementById('blocation');
const secDiv= document.getElementById('subtypeDiv');
const secondD= document.getElementById('subtype');

firstD.addEventListener('change',()=>{
  secDiv.style.display='block';

  switch(firstD.options[firstD.selectedIndex].value){
    case 'One':
      secondD.removeAttribute('multiple');
      break;
    case 'Multiple':
      secondD.setAttribute('multiple','true');
      break;
    case 'Online':
      secondD.removeAttribute('multiple');
      break;
  }
});
```

Check the link mentioned in comment!

Comment: I replaced my script with yours and it didn't do anything on select of any dropdown. The subtype didn't show at all

Comment: I believe it is working. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/quazwro2/